# PHP Socket, not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, sockets, resources, stream, irc

I know this has been asked before, but I just can't get it to work.

fgets() and feof() gives an error for not valid stream resource.

socket

```
$socket =  fsockopen($settings['server'], $settings['port'], $errno, $errstr, 20);
```

loop

```
        while(!feof($socket)) {
            interface_retrieve_buffer();
```

interface_retrieve_buffer()

```
function interface_retrieve_buffer() {
    global $buffer,$socket;
    $buffer = fgets($socket);
}
```

It's all done in that order using various functions, but I'm guessing the socket times out real quick and that results in the errors being sent?

It's filling my HDD (90 GB in ~4h) and I really need to fix this, I've tried several solutions and none of them has worked.

Thanks!

EDIT:
More code: http://pastebin.com/BwqJ0CJQ and http://pastebin.com/gcFEAkRS

Comment: `fsockopen()` failed and returned false. `$errno` and `$errstr`, if you output them, will show you an error message explaining why.

Comment: But it's all working, except after a while it fails... Why would it fail when it's working at first?

Comment: In order for "not a valid stream resource" errors to occur, you would have had to reassign `$socket` somewhere in your code - even a closed socket is still a valid stream resource. Can you show your full code? Please use a pastebin if it is very long.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A3AsLggq

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look now

Comment: Because the code is littered with `global` imports it's kinda hard to determine exactly where it's going wrong - it may not be in any of the code you show (since there are obviously other files involved - you file doesn't define `load_settings()` anywhere). This whole thing really need rewriting to use dependency injection to get the socket resource to where it needs to be. However, as a temporary work around, you can probably just use `is_resource($socket) && !feof($socket)` as the `while` condition. This should cause the inner loop to break when the socket is no longer valid.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I appreciate you taking a look. I'll try the work around.

Comment: Yeah, the work around didn't quite work. pastebin of the entire 2 files http://pastebin.com/BwqJ0CJQ and http://pastebin.com/gcFEAkRS . Not sure if that's any help to anyone.